# App Crashing on startup - IOS(React Native)

Tags: ios, react-native

While upgrading application with one of the third party library getting below error & stacktrace

```
dyld[13819]: Library not loaded: @rpath/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel
  Referenced from: <EAE4836E-B166-3820-A641-7AADA4130D07> /Users/shreeganesha/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B447388-4459-439F-8CED-7197C6F76562/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B148F5EE-B378-47A7-BCE0-4329D8C1C593/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/JustRideSDK.framework/JustRideSDK
  Reason: tried: '/Users/shreeganesha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXX-fplmohofvfuusecqaqwnulnyleoe/Build/Products/Vamos Release-iphonesimulator/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2), '/Users/shreeganesha/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B447388-4459-439F-8CED-7197C6F76562/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B148F5EE-B378-47A7-BCE0-4329D8C1C593/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2), '/Users/shreeganesha/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B447388-4459-439F-8CED-7197C6F76562/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B148F5EE-B378-47A7-BCE0-4329D8C1C593/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/JustRideSDK.framework/Frameworks/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2), '/Users/shreeganesha/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B447388-4459-439F-8CED-7197C6F76562/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/Frameworks/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2), '/Users/shreeganesha/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B447388-4459-439F-8CED-7197C6F76562/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B148F5EE-B378-47A7-BCE0-4329D8C1C593/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2), '/Users/shreeganesha/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B447388-4459-439F-8CED-7197C6F76562/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B148F5EE-B378-47A7-BCE0-4329D8C1C593/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/JustRideSDK.framework/Frameworks/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2), '/Users/shreeganesha/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2, no dyld cache), '/Users/shreeganesha/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2, no dyld cache), '/Users/shreeganesha/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B447388-4459-439F-8CED-7197C6F76562/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B148F5EE-B378-47A7-BCE0-4329D8C1C593/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2), '/Users/shreeganesha/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B447388-4459-439F-8CED-7197C6F76562/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B148F5EE-B378-47A7-BCE0-4329D8C1C593/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2), '/Users/shreeganesha/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B447388-4459-439F-8CED-7197C6F76562/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B148F5EE-B378-47A7-BCE0-4329D8C1C593/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2), '/Users/shreeganesha/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2, no dyld cache), '/Users/shreeganesha/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/swift/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2, no dyld cache), '/Users/shreeganesha/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B447388-4459-439F-8CED-7197C6F76562/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B148F5EE-B378-47A7-BCE0-4329D8C1C593/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2), '/Users/shreeganesha/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B447388-4459-439F-8CED-7197C6F76562/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B148F5EE-B378-47A7-BCE0-4329D8C1C593/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2), '/Users/shreeganesha/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B447388-4459-439F-8CED-7197C6F76562/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B148F5EE-B378-47A7-BCE0-4329D8C1C593/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2), '/Users/shreeganesha/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel' (errno=2)
```

Trying to understand whats causing this issue & any clue on fix for the same.